# Loop through array of shuffled WebElements without them getting stale

Tags: python, arrays, loops, selenium

My dilemma is that if I use

```
a=[]
a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("card")
random.shuffle(a)
for card in a:
    nextup=(str(card.text) + '\n' + "_" * 15)
    do a bunch of stuff that takes about 10 min
```

The first round works but then I get a StaleElementException because it clicks links and goes to diff pages. So then I switched to this:

```
a=[]
a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("card")
i=0
cardnum=len(a)
while i != cardnum:
    i += 1 #needed because first element thats found doesnt work
    a=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("card") #also needed to refresh the list
    random.shuffle(a) 
    nextup=(str(card.text) + '\n' + "_" * 15)
    do a bunch of stuff that takes about 10 min
```

The problem with this one is the i variable because the same card could be clicked due to the shuffle with each loop. Then I added a catch to check if card had already been clicked and continue if it has. Sounds like it'd work but sadly the i variable counts these and then eventually counts past the index. I thought about periodically setting i back to 1 but I do not know if it will work. Edit: would make an infinite loop since once all are clicked i will be zero and it will never exit.

I know the code works it's been tested extensively, however, bots get banned for not being humanlike and random. The basics of this script is goes thru a list of categories and then goes thru all the cards in a category. Tried randomizing the categories but similar dilemma because to refresh the list you have to remake array in each loop like the above block then comes the problem with categories already being completed would be clicked again... Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code that determine if the card has been clicked? I think you just need to add more conditions there. (1) Add maximum number of loop. (2) set i= i-1.

Comment: @Buaban if "WATCHED" in nextup:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that, as you interact with the page, the DOM gets refreshed, eventually causing the elements you've been storing to go stale.

Rather than keeping a list of the elements, keep a reference to their individual element paths, and reacquire the elements as needed:

```
# The base css path for all the cards
base_card_css_path = ".card"

# Get all the target elements. You are only doing this to
# get a count of the number of elements on the page
card_elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(base_card_css_path)

# Convert this to a list of indexes, starting with 1
card_indexes = list(range(1, len(card_elems)+1))

# Shuffle it
random.shuffle(card_indexes)

# Use `:nth-child(X)` syntax to get these elements on an as needed basis
for index in card_indexes:
    card_css = base_card_css_path + ":nth-child({0})".format(index)
    card = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(card_css)
    nextup=(str(card.text) + '\n' + "_" * 15)
    # do a bunch of stuff that takes about 10 min
```

(The above is untested for obvious reasons)